# Error message in console from using chart.js

Tags: javascript, csv, chart.js

```
function draw() {
    
    const labels = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
    ];

    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'test',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
        }]
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {}
    };



    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );


}
```

This is my code and i keep getting this error message:

"Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused."

Apart from this error code, my chart is able to display perfectly with no problems.

Comment: Please mention the error. The above link is not working

Comment: alright i've edited it!

Comment: In order to be able to draw another chart on the same canvas, is `.destroy()`. You must call it on the previously created chart object. You may also use the same variable for both charts.  So before creating new chart you should destroy the canvas.  Maybe calling this before making new  chart will do the work `myChart.destroy()`

Comment: When i added ```myChart.destroy()``` before making new chart it displays another error message that states "Cannot access 'myChart' before initialization". But if i were to add ```myChart.destroy()``` at the end after i initialized 'myChart', my chart is gone and there isn't any error code for it.

Comment: Do you have two charts?

Comment: I only have 1 chart on the whole file

Comment: I posted answer See if it works

Answer (score 1):

Call `myChart.destroy()` before creating the new **Chart**. First declare `myChart` it globally and then initialize it.

```
let myChart = null;
function draw() {
    
    const labels = [
        'January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
    ];

    const data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'test',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
        }]
    };

    const config = {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: {}
    };

    if(myChart !== null){
        myChart.destroy();
    }

    myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config
    );

}
```

Comment: Hi this doesn't work for me. I tried it and now its just creating many instances over and over again. etc: ID:1 ID:2 .....